# not defined error c++ Static methods declared

Tags: c++

I have a static method in class as follows in file **Convert.h**

```
class Convert
{
    public :
    static string convertIntToStr(unsigned int integer);    
};
```

In **Convert.cpp**

```
string 
Convert::convertIntToStr(unsigned int integer) 
{
    ostringstream ostr;
    ostr <<  integer;
    return ostr.str();
}
```

I use this in some other class method in another .cpp file as Convert::convertIntToStr, but I get linking error, which says undefined reference to Convert::convertIntToStr(unsigned int). Could you please let me know what could be wrong?

Comment: This is a link error. So we need to see how you're linking your executable.

Comment: Static member functions are not meant to be visible from another translation unit. If you want it to be visible, define the function in header file.

Comment: This might be really silly, but did you include convert.h?

Comment: @AdityaKumar That's not correct. They are perfectly visible just like other member functions.

Answer (score 4):

This should really be a comment, but I'm new to SO and it doesn't let me add comments yet.

Sorry if this is a silly question, but are you sure Convert.cpp was added to your project?  It sounds like Convert.cpp is not being compiled into an object for the linker.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you are properly linking all of your object files.

Answer (score 3):

It's a linker error and happens when it can't find the definition of a function, global variable, etc... are you linking all of your objects files?

Answer (score 3):

if you have defined the Convert in a namespace make sure that you are including that namespace when you call. Something like

```
namespace::Convert::convertIntToStr(...)
```

or the calling class is in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Put class convert in a header file, and include the same in the other .cpp file

```
#ifndef CONVERT.H_
#define CONVERT.H_
class Convert
{
    public :
    static string convertIntToStr(unsigned int integer);    
};
#end if
```

Include it as `#include "convert.h"` in the other file.